# GNU MAKE Where is path set for "Entering Directory ..."

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

When executing make.exe, my code fails because of case sensitivity of the drive letter.

Currently, my make prints out:

`make.exe[3]: Entering directory 'C:/...'` (fails).

On another computer, with the same source I get:

`make.exe[3]: Entering directory 'c:/...'` (works).

I am guessing it has to do with the case sensitivity of the drive letter (because of gnu make).

I was wondering where is the drive letter set? Is it somewhere in the path?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by were the drive letter is set.  It's not really set anywhere.

You might like to try running:

```
make -C c:\whatever
```

to tell make to change to a particular directory before processing the Makefile.